# Biztalk Removing Schemas and orchestration from Deployed project

Tags: schema, biztalk, orchestration

I have 2 projects that reference the `X12_00401_214.xsd`.  I was getting the message about duplicate schemas in the send pipeline.

Following advice I found online I create a common project and changed the map and orchestration references to the schema in the common project.

When I try to deploy the project, biztalk removes the schemas and orchestration from the other deployed EDI 214 project.  If I try to redeploy to fix it, it removes them from the other project.

Is this because each project references the same common schema and biztalk is replacing the schemas and orchestrations?

I have tried redoing the orchestrations to make sure the variables were unique.

Is there a step I am missing here?

Comment: Looks like biztalk is uninstalling the other application from the gac because it is deploying the shared dll with each project deployment. Is there a way to prevent this:

Answer (score 2):

I finally traced the issue to the reference to the shared project.   I had it referenced as a project reference.   On each projected deploy it rebuild and deployed the shared project.  This caused biztalk to drop the binding and undeploy the parts of the other project that referenced the shared project.

When I changed the project to reference only the compiled DLL, I no longer had the issue and both projects are now working.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 projects that reference the X12_00401_214.xsd. I was getting
>   the message about duplicate schemas in the send pipeline.

XMLNS#Root combinations of schemas must be unique. You are right that it is annoying that duplicates can be deployed and this error is only detected at run time.

> Is this because each project references the same common schema and
>   biztalk is replacing the schemas and orchestrations?

I believe you may be adding your common schemas project to both your dependent EDI BizTalk applications. In this case, the schemas assembly will be added to the Resources of both projects, and you will have issues such as above.

The general advice here is to move common artifacts like shared or framework schemas, envelopes, pipelines, and possibly standard Exception Handling orchs etc into one or more separate BizTalk Applications (e.g. `EDICommon`) and define an application dependency on this from your 2 EDI Applications. There is an in depth article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578278.aspx). (There is no need for a BizTalk application to have any orchs or actually do any processing - it can just be a container for artifacts).

One caveat - you will need to uninstall all dependent Apps if your common schemas App changes significantly and you need to redeploy.